# Fluidtypo3 Flux - save in table field

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to develop a frontend extensions with typo3 - fluidcontent. Is it possible to use the bodytext field of the tt_content table instead of the flexform field?

I would like to connect this text element with the `tt_content.bodytext` field.

```
<flux:field.text name="bodytext" label="Content" />
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Flux internally generates data structures in so-called Flexforms, so it has to use the pi_flexform field. I doubt that you can easily change this.

Comment: I would like to save the rendering specific settings in flexforms. The content should stay inside the database columns.
Furthermore I would like to use a custom data model. I'm trying to figure out if I should use fluidcontent or typo3 - extbase with fluid.

Comment: FluidTYPO3 always uses the flexform - I doubt it's possible to store the content in other database columns. But you could use `fluid_styled_content` (new in 7.x), that should allow you to use database columns. Defining the backend forms is probably a bit more tedious (you have to do it via TCA config), but you get a normalized database structure.

Comment: At the moment I'm working with fluid_styled_content ce. I like the clean approach from fluidcontent but I don't like to have content in flexforms. I think I will go on with fluid_styled_content.

Answer (score 3):

You can force Flux to save to the record itself, rather than the flexform field, *by prefixing your field names with the name of the table that your form applies to*. For example, since this implementation is for `tt_content`, you can name the field `tt_content.bodytext` and the value will be saved to that field instead.