# How can I store flux form fields defined in TYPO3 page templates in database columns instead of flex fields?

Tags: typo3, flux

Using flux to create custom content elements for TYPO3, fields that are defined in a flux:form are stored in a flex field as XML by default. By the solution Claus Due pointed out here ([Fluidtypo3 Flux - save in table field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245182/fluidtypo3-flux-save-in-table-field/39307390#39307390)), they can also be stored as individual columns in tt_content.

Now, when creating page templates and defining template parameters as flux input fields, could those be stored as indiviual columns in the "pages" table?

The obvious approach to do this in the same way as described for content elements, i.e.:

```
<flux:field.text name="pages.extrafield" label="Content" />
```

did not work. (I created the field "extrafield" in the pages table using my extension's ext_tables.sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you used is the correct one, but in order to get the field saved it first must be 1) allowed for the user who saves and 2) shown somewhere in the form; types `passthrough` and `none` should also work.

The last requirement is a safeguard added in a recent major version and is there to prevent doing things that normally would be prohibited by access settings or field availability.